# How to escape double quotes in a string for json parser in Java

Tags: java, json

I got a string like below:

```
{
    "test": [
        "",
        "abc",
        "IF(Var218 = "charlie") AND (Var85 ≤ 0) AND (Var207 = \"some value\"; \"du\") THEN Appetency = 1 ",
        "",
        """"
    ]
}
```

The string will be parsed as a JSON object, now the question is how should I escape some of the double quotes in the string in Java effectively?

The string above is just one example, and please notice not all double quotes in the string should be escaped, only double quotes such as in "charlie" and """" should be escaped, otherwise json parser will not parse the string correctly. Expected result should be like:

```
{
    "test": [
        "",
        "abc",
        "IF(Var218 = \"charlie\") AND (Var85 ≤ 0) AND (Var207 = \"some value\"; \"du\") THEN Appetency = 1 ",
        "",
        "\"\""
    ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: is your json valid, check [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Are you not already escaping the double quotes for Var207 with a \"

Comment: What you are trying to do is not very clear to me, can you elaborate please?

Comment: The json string is not valid, only part of the string has been escaped, but not all.

Comment: Are you not just missing Var218 = \"charlie\"

Comment: The string is just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the Gson library for this.
But it looks like this is what you are asking for.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
...
public void stuff()
    {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        data.add("");
        data.add("abc");
        data.add("IF(Var218 = \"charlie\") AND (Var85 &le; 0) AND (Var207 = \"some value\"; \"du\") THEN Appetency = 1 ");
        data.add("\"\"");

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();

        JsonObject test = new JsonObject();
        JsonElement jsonData = gson.toJsonTree(data, new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType());
        test.add("test", jsonData);

        String json = gson.toJson(test);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
```

This will produce:

```
{
  "test":[
    "",
    "abc",
    "IF(Var218 = \"charlie\") AND (Var85 &le; 0) AND (Var207 = \"some value\"; \"du\") THEN Appetency = 1 ",
    "",
    "\"\""
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how to do this in Java because this string is just one example.

Answer (score 3):

In java you escape `"` by `\"` and the same goes for JSON. The problem is that `\"` does not include a backward slash, so you need to escape that as well:

```
String json = "hello \\\"world\\\""; // hello "world"
```

Notice the three (3) backwards slash.

Answer (score 1):

The following algorithm should work with the JSON String in `input`

```
String progress = "";
for(int c = 0; c < input.length(); c++){
    char ch = input.charAt(c);
    if(ch == '\\'){    // Skip if the next character is already escaped
        c++;
        continue;
    }
    if(ch == '\"') progress += "\\\""; // Results in \"
    else progress += ch;    // Add the character to progress
}
```

The escaped String is now in `progress`

Comment: This will escape double quotes required by json parser, actually only double quotes in map values should be escaped.

Comment: @BruceLi I suggest you add that detail to the question, as you never mention that only some of the quotes should be escaped

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I don;t see the point bacause you are escaping your cdouble quoted correct

```
"\"\"" // this will produce ""
```

So simple before each " place one \

Answer (score 0):

```
package ezvcard;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.List;

public class MyTests {

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        String json = "{\"test\": [\"\", \"abc\", \"IF(Var218 = \"charlie\") AND (Var85 ≤ 0) AND (Var207 = \\\"some value\\\"; \\\"du\\\") THEN Appetency = 1 \", \"\", \"\"\"\"]}";
        String newJson = json
                .replaceAll("\"]", "\']")
                .replaceAll("\\[\"", "\\[\'")
                .replaceAll("\\{\"", "\\{\'")
                .replaceAll("\"}", "\'}")
                .replaceAll("\",", "\',")
                .replaceAll(",\"", ",\'")
                .replaceAll(", \"", ", \'")
                .replaceAll("\":", "\':")
                .replaceAll(":\"", ":\'");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        MyTest test = gson.fromJson(newJson, MyTest.class);
        
        for (String s : test.test) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
    public static class MyTest {
        List<String> test;
    
    }
}
```