# not able to create Java Object from Json having double quote in value

Tags: java, json, gson

I have same query. My JSON is as below.

```
String json="{ "credentials": { "password": "Password"123", "emailAddress": "skylineadmin@gmail.com" }, "clientTimeMs": 1582006455421, "callerRole": 0 }"
```

key = password and value is **"Password"123"** it contains " (double quote).. I am not able to create a java object from this json as it is invalidated.

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
gson.fromJson(json, PasswordResetDetails.java);
```

Above code snippet is not Working.

Comment: Hello there!
What you have there is not valid JSON.
Your source should only provide valid JSON.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape double quotes in a string for json parser in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501523/how-to-escape-double-quotes-in-a-string-for-json-parser-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for learning / testing purpose all you need to do is escaping the double quote using :

```
String json="{ "credentials": { "password": "Password\"123", "emailAddress": "skylineadmin@gmail.com" }, "clientTimeMs": 1582006455421, "callerRole": 0 }"
```

If this is a real scenario then I would like to suggest to change the source in order to make sure it provides valid JSON.

There are countless possibilities to check if your JSON is valid (JSON linting), here's [one](https://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: its real scenario. From reset password screen user can provide any password. let's say Password"123 this password string with double quote is coming at server side along with other details in a json as I mentioned above. so is there any generic solution for this. because user can provide any password. with double quote it is failing to created java object. even if I use escape chanracter after executing this java line String comes like "password": "Password"123"...which again fails to create java object with gson.fromJson...

Comment: Then my suggestion is to fix this behaviour on the source.
If input is not sanitized it means that you are also risking other type of attacks.